# Remove black transparency from background from date picker

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using a library for a calendar, https://github.com/benznest/flutter_rounded_date_picker, but I think this is a Flutter question and doesn't have to do with the library.

I copied all the files into my project, to be able to style freely.

However, I cannot remove the background black transparency that comes after opening the calendar.

Here is the relevant code (I believe this is the relevant code)

```
final Dialog dialog = Dialog(
  child: OrientationBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, Orientation orientation) {
    assert(orientation != null);
    final Widget header = FlutterRoundedDatePickerHeader(
        selectedDate: _selectedDate,
        mode: _mode,
        onModeChanged: _handleModeChanged,
        orientation: orientation,
        era: widget.era,
        borderRadius: widget.borderRadius,
        imageHeader: widget.imageHeader,
        description: widget.description,
        fontFamily: widget.fontFamily,
        style: widget.styleDatePicker);
    switch (orientation) {
      case Orientation.portrait:
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: backgroundPicker,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.borderRadius),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              header,
              if (widget.height == null)
                Flexible(child: picker)
              else
                SizedBox(
                  height: widget.height,
                  child: picker,
                ),
              actions,
            ],
          ),
        );
      case Orientation.landscape:
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: backgroundPicker,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.borderRadius),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(flex: 1, child: header),
              Flexible(
                flex: 2, // have the picker take up 2/3 of the dialog width
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(child: picker),
                    actions,
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
    }
    return null;
  }),
);
```

I tried adding

```
final Dialog dialog = Dialog(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent
```

but it didn't work

I also tried replacing Dialog with Material, and put a bounded container inside,

```
Material(
  color: Colors.transparent,
  shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
  child: Align(
```

but the black transparency in the background of the calendar does not go away.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

---

This is how it is called

```
void _handleDateChange() async {
final date = await showRoundedDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: DateTime.now(),
    firstDate: someDateTime,
    lastDate: someOtherDateTime,
  )        
}
```

Comment: please add a screenshot of what you are getting now

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede here is a screenshot from their repo. See the black transparent background https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benznest/flutter_rounded_date_picker/master/screenshots/1.png

Comment: Where you are calling your `dialog`?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede I am calling when clicking a textFormField in a scaffold. But the image from the repo has the background too. I was thinking it may have to do with some theme color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

no black screen now.

You need `barrierColor: Colors.transparent` in showDialog function call
and `barrierDismissible: true` change this if you want to block outside click dismiss dialog -> false.

```
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return dialog;
      },
      barrierDismissible: true,
      barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
    );
  }
```

Also there is a shadow for dialog if you want to remove that also.

```
final Dialog dialog = Dialog(
  ...
  elevation: 0,
);
```

there will not be any shadow or any backdrop.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand where to put your code. I tried changing ----final Dialog dialog = ---- to ----final dynamic dialog = ---- and wrapping the dialog in your function and I get ---Expected a value of type 'Widget', but got one of type '(BuildContext) => Null'. ---- Where the dialog is called it goes like this:---- return Theme(
      data: theme,
      child: dialog,
    ); ---- Where do I add your code? is it in the button that calls the calendar? Thank you

Comment: Thank you! I found it!. I have to wailt 12 hours to be able to grant the award, but consider given ( barrierDismissible: true doesn't seem to be necessary when Color is transparent)

Comment: yes : barrierDismissible is just to dismiss the dialog, as I often work on Flutter web i turn it on, so that user can exit without pressing hardware back or cancel button, it's just for UI/UX user ease.

Comment: yes but if barrierColor is transparent barrierDismissible is true by default

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the package limit. ([flutter_rounded_date_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rounded_date_picker)) 1.0.5+1

Inner `showRoundedDatePicker` source, it call `showDialog` at the end (leave *barrierColor* value null)

```
Future<DateTime> showRoundedDatePicker(
...
  return await showDialog<DateTime>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: barrierDismissible,
    builder: (_) => Theme(data: theme, child: child),
  );
}
```

Inside `showDialog`, it will set barrierColor to black54 if it is null:

```
Future<T?> showDialog<T>({
  ...
  return showGeneralDialog(
    ...
    barrierColor: barrierColor ?? Colors.black54,
    ...
  );
}
```

You can do as follow:

1. Add request to the package provider in [github](https://github.com/benznest/flutter_rounded_date_picker/issues) and wait for the update
2. Find another data picker package
3. Make your own custom date_picker